# li padding issue in mpdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, mpdf

I have the following piece of code:

```
<ol>
     <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    </ol>
```

And my CSS is the following:

```
li {
    padding-top: 200px !important;
    padding-bottom: 200px !important;
}
```

padding is not working in PDF creation

Comment: Good to know. Where did you hide the question?

Comment: where is the pdf code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Documentation of mPDF (http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34) `LI` tags only support `list-style-` properties up to mPDF < 6.0. From 6.0 and higher `LI` tags are handled as Block level tags and support `padding`.